# Expresión regular para validar DNI

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Necesito una expresión regular para validar un DNI argentino, es decir, necesitaría que solo acepte números y algún punto opcionalmente. Por ejemplo: deberia tomar un dni: `43.553.938` y también debería poder permitir el mismo dni, sin puntos (`43553938`) sin ningún problema.
La longitud máxima debería ser de 9 caracteres y la mínima de 7. Fuera de ese rango no debería aceptar el input.
Hasta el momento intenté con otras expresiones regulares como esta

```
(/^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$/)
```

pero no me está funcionando.

Comment: Hola, hasta el momento intente con otras expresiones regulares como esta (/^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$/) pero no me esta funcionando

Comment: Perdón, el dni de que pais? menor a 1 millon porque no?

Comment: Buen dia, el dni es argentino, es decir, entre 7 y 8 caracteres (SIN LETRAS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimo un millon (7 digitos), maximo 999 millones (9 digitos), pero debe permitir puntos de mil opcionalmente, te propongo esta:
`^[\d]{1,3}\.?[\d]{3,3}\.?[\d]{3,3}$`
Pruebala y si javascript no te hace match puedes intentar cambiar **[\d]** por **[0-9]**.

Comment: Un exito!!! Muchisimas gracias. Funcionó sin tener que hacer el cambio por [0-9]

Comment: @thiago [\d] es lo mismo que [0-9], solo que algunos lenguajes no lo aceptan.

Comment: `[\d]{3,3}` es lo mismo que `\d{3}`

Comment: @Pollo si, pero a mi parecer queda mas cómodo `[\d]{3,3}` por compatibilidad con todos los lenguajes, ya que algunos exigen numero mínimo y numero máximo. Pero para el caso puntual de javascript probablemente se puede usar `\d{3}` sin problema.

Comment: @AgileSoul ¿qué dialecto de regex o en qué lenguaje se exige usar a ambos límites? No recuerdo ninguno en el que no se pueda. Mismo con `[\d]` versus `\d`

Comment: @Pollo por ejemplo en el `grep -E` de linux no te vale poner `[\d]` o `\d`, te fuerza a poner `[0-9]` pero puedes ponerlo si lo cambias por una regex de tipo perl: `grep -P`. Ahora cuando usas la función `str.match` en javascript esta no acepta que pongamos un valor mínimo sin un valor máximo, es decir si quisiéramos usar `\d{1,}` para mínimo un digito y máximo los que sean, esta función no lo permite, pero en otros compiladores de regex si lo permiten.

Comment: Cuando e usado la comparación `[[ $variableTexto =~  $regex ]]` en bash, la regex no me admite cosas como `\s`, `\w`, `\d`, etc.

Comment: @AgileSoul Sí se puede omitir el límite máximo en `String.match()`. Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/nrwm76va/ .  Algunos dialectos no implementan a `\d`, pero siempre que funcione con `[\d]` va a funcionar con `\d`, y eso es lo que te comentaba antes: `[\d]` es lo mismo que `\d` y `{3,3}` es lo mismo que `{3}` en todos los que conozco. Obviamente si encontrás alguno donde no se cumpla, me intriga saberlo.

Comment: Tiene razón, estoy desactualizado, hace tiempo no se podía omitir el limite máximo en String.match(), supongo que fue debido a una actualización que ahora se puede.